# How to store multiple checked Checkbox values in DB using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am developing a project using ASP MVC and stored procedures (SQL Server), I want to store checked checkbox items in database. I've tried to add a `List<string>` type in model in order to access these value and then store them in the database.

The problem that the relational databases are designed specifically to store one value per row/column combination. In order to store more than one value, I must serialize my list into a single value for storage, then deserialize it upon retrieval.

That's my view markup:

```
               <h6>Items</h6>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label class="anim">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Soups" name="Items">
                                <span>Soups</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label class="anim">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Burger" name="Items" >
                                <span>Burger</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label class="anim">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Drinks" name="Items">
                                <span>Drinks</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label class="anim">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Desserts" name="Items">
                                <span>Desserts</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Method `AddBestellung`:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddNewBestellung", con))
        {
            foreach(var item in bs.Items)
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Items", item);
            }

            // Another saved parameters...

            con.Open();
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            if (i >= 1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    string e = ex.Message;
    return false;
}

private static string Connection()
{
    return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["deliverycon"].ToString();
}
```

Model:

```
public List<string> Items { get; set; }
```

Comment: you could try using a Flags Enumeration

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Actually, since you're using SQL Server, you could also store your array of checkbox values as XML.

Comment: and how about the sql datatype

Comment: @RichBryant thanks but can you explain more how it will be as XML

Comment: Okay, I'll do both options as Answers and you can try them.

Comment: ok a lot of thanks :)

Comment: If you're using **stored procedures**, you must declare that when using a `SqlCommand`! Add this line after the creation : `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`

Comment: @marc_s thanks but it is already exist, I didn't only copy it sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flags Enumeration -

```
[Flags]
public enum ItemStorage
{
    Soups = 1,
    Burger = 2,
    Drinks = 4,
    Dessert = 8,
    Cheese = 16
}
```

I added the Cheese just to emphasise the binary nature of the Flags enum.

And here's your other code -

```
public class Stuff
{
    private List<string> Items;
    private static string Connection()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["deliverycon"].ToString();
    }

    public bool DoStuff()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection()))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddNewBestellung", con))
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Items", (int)ConstuctEnumValueFromList(Items));
                    //other saved parameters...

                    con.Open();
                    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();

                    if (i >= 1)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string e = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }

    private ItemStorage ConstuctEnumValueFromList(List<string> list)
    {
        var result = new ItemStorage();
        if (list.Any())
        {
            var separatedList = string.join(",", list)
            bool success = Enum.TryParse<ItemStorage>(separatedList, out result)
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In this case, you can simply store the Items field as a single integer and cast it back to ItemStorage when retrieving like so -

```
int i = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8;
var items = (ItemStorage)i;
Console.WriteLine(items.ToString());
```

This should give you
"Soups, Burger, Drinks, Desserts";

Comment: Thanks, i have to write the Flags enumeration in model ?

Comment: Or simply an integer value.  Either is fine.

Comment: Ok I will try and let you know

Comment: Following your suggestion, when I check more than 1 value, only the first checked one is stored in DB

Comment: That's interesting.  Try putting a breakpoint in the ConstuctEnumValueFromList(List<string> list) method and stepping through.

Comment: the Items get now null value

Comment: right.  You ARE passing in your list of items, right?  The class structure I gave you is only intended as an example.

Comment: yes, I thought that is solution, but it appeared for me a lil weired coz I have two definitions of parameters Items in My model and in Controller and I don't know which type will take Items in Model and in DB Schema

Comment: well, the DB schema should just be looking for a single integer field.

As long as you pass the populated `List<string>` into your method that actually saves the data, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't serialize/deserialize. This will be painful to use afterward.

Imagine you need to retrieve objects that have items 1 and 5 checked.
If it's serialized as a string it's less efficient and easy that to store it as follow.

Let's say you have a "Person" table and you want to check the list of "Consoles" they own.

You'll have table **person** :

- id int  primary key
- Name varchar not null

and the table **console**

- id int primary_key
- name varchar not null

and the table to store the console owned :

**owned_console**

- id int primary key
- person_id int  (foreign key => person(id))
- console_id int (foreign key => console(id))

In your code, you will insert a record per checkbox checked.

Person:

- (1)Thomas
- (2)Pierre

Console:

- (1)NES
- (2)MegaDrive
- (3)NeoGeo

owned_console:

- (1)(1)
- (1)(2)
- (1)(3)
- (2)(1)
- (2)(1)

And then you can do things like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM   person p
INNER  JOIN owned_console oc
ON     p.id = oc.person_id
WHERE  oc.console_id IN (3,1);
```

Comment: thanks but it is a lil complicated with creating new table, I want only only to store more than one in a column,

Comment: I disagree, it's very simple.  See other answer.  Next I'll serialize to XML so you can see how easy that is, too.

Comment: @Exact: this ***IS*** the **proper, relational way** of doing things. You should **never ever** store multiple values into a single cell - just say ***NO!*** to comma-separated values in a cell - you'll be looking at a maintenance nightmare down the road! Do it properly - from the beginning !

Comment: @Thomas: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Comment: you can store multiple values if you're happy that you won't be querying them.  Or if you're happy storing those multiple values in an XML column and you are happy writing to SQLXML to query them.

Comment: @marc_s ok but is there then any solution to store multiple data

Comment: @Exact: the **proper relational way** to store multiple values is a separate table (with one row for each value) which handles your "multiple values" for a single entity

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the link. I find the old way shorter and more readable despite what the article says. I'm using the ANSI-92 when I can't do otherwise with mariaDB/MySQL. (I'm used to use the Oracle (+) syntax, which I found also more practical)

Comment: I notice you're not actually answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

XML Serialization

First, make sure you're familiar with [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/create-xml-data-type-variables-and-columns).  This method requires that you store your Items collection to an XML column in SQL Server.  It also has the advantage that you can query against that column, provided you're not afraid of SQLXML and XPath.  Many developers are.

Once you have that, everything looks very similar (if a little simpler).

```
public class Stuff
{
    private List<string> Items;
    private static string Connection()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["deliverycon"].ToString();
    }

    public bool DoStuff()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection()))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddNewBestellung", con))
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Items", ConstructXmlFromList(Items));
                    //other saved parameters...

                    con.Open();
                    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();

                    if (i >= 1)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string e = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static T FromXML<T>(string xml)
    {
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
        }
    }

    public string ToXML<T>(T obj)
    {
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder()))
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, obj);
            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    private string ConstructXmlFromList(List<string> list)
    {
        return ToXML(list);
    }
}
```

And again, it's easy to rehydrate the XML fragment into the `List<string>` that you started with.  You'd simply use

```
var myList = FromXML<List<string>>(fieldValue);
```